# How to play MPEG4 Visual with HTML5 <video>?

Tags: video, html, mp4, h.264, html5-video

I currently use this to play AVC (H.264 or MPEG-4 Part 10) videos.

```
<video controls preload>
  <source src="xyz.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

However, that doesn't work for MP4V (MPEG-4 Visual or MPEG-4 Part 2) videos. I tried `codecs="mp4v.20.8, mp4a.40.2"` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Does any of the major browsers support MP4V in HTML5 `<video>`?  If yes, what type/codecs should I specify in the `<source>` tag? Alternatively, do Flash players like [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) support MP4V?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293292/unable-to-play-video-in-html5/6330517#6330517

Comment: Try leaving out the codecs altogether and let the browser decide?

Comment: @Google: Not a duplicate question because (1) they wanted to play AVI, not MP4, (2) their select answer has nothing to do with this question, (3) the answer your link points to may be a very compatible way to use HTML5 video, but does not address my main question - whether any of the major browsers support MP4 videos with MPEG-4 Part 2 codecs.

Comment: @IanDevlin: I did try that, but it has been a year now, so perhaps I should try again :-)

Comment: Haha so sorry, I didn't check the date at all!

Answer (score -5):

MP4 Supporting Browser: IE9+,Chrome 4+, Safari 3.2+, Andriod 2.1+

Flash Player supports MP4 since version 9.0.115.0

Comment: OP is asking about the encoding format (mpeg4), not the container format (mp4).