# Unable to play video in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video

I just started learning HTML5, I started with normal text file and changed its extension to .html and added the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <body>

  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="D:\Movies\Troy (2004).avi" type="video/avi" /> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I am using FireFox 4.0.

Comment: I think you forgot the part where you described the problem you were having, then ask the question that helps us help you.

Comment: "D:\Movies\Troy (2004).avi" is not a URL, and cannot be used in a `src` attribute.

Comment: thanx, I changed the question title...So what should be the source, and how will html locate that file??

Comment: You have to use file:/// URIs.

Comment: @passcod, thanx its working for me know. your comment should be an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Firefox doesn't support the avi container format](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements)

Comment: I also tried this in Google Chrome, still no success...is this anything to do with the video source I specified? is it something like file should be present in a application like we create in asp.net??

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't support the avi container format either. You have to use a supported video.

Comment: Correction: AVI ain't supported by _any_ browser.

Comment: That is more additional information than a correction. I'm not sure it is entirely true though, I seem to remember reading something about some browser using the underlying Windows media framework (which can take plugins), so if AVI support is available in that then it will be in the browser too).

Answer (score 2):

Firefox doesn't support the avi format. Only ogg and webm are supported as also stated in [this](http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming-1/html5-chrome-firefox-mpeg-video-support-718068.html) topic.

Edit: Peter Paul Koch has an more detailed overview of supported codecs in the different browsers available nowadays. See the article [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/index.html).

Comment: @passcod You're right, forgotten about that one. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a few things to make this work cross-browser, and as stated above, firefox doesn't play well with the AVI container format.

Read this:
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html
Or you could check out a javascript solution like this that helps make things a bit easier:
http://videojs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Convert your movie with Miro Video Converter or similar software

Miro - http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

and you might want to make the player more compatible with multiple browsers.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

example from http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp

Comment: This is good answer. (you mention all the common formats that should works). But how can you change the src like playing new films with same container?

Comment: There is a great but ugly way to do it in .net use a panel and build the videotag in codebehind worked great for me at http://finalfantasyworld.net/Movies/Movies.aspx

or there shoud be a javascript way, that i cannot get to work

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome do not support avi format , but the **strange** thing is if you just drop a avi file into the browser it plays just fine ! . I wonder when these browser have the capability of playing these files why are they not put in the html5 tag :\